# Postgres 14 | dblink_get_connections() | Boolean Test for Connection Exists Returns NULL

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postgres, and am working on inter-database queries etc. All is working well...except:
Before the "meat" of any work, I would like to test the existence of the relevant database connection, and raise an exception (and abort the script) if it has not been created.
To that end, I have the following code block:

```
DO $$
    DECLARE
        connectionIsGood boolean := (select 'my_connection' = ANY (dblink_get_connections()));
    BEGIN   
        RAISE INFO 'connectionIsGood=%', connectionIsGood;
    
        IF (connectionIsGood != true)
        THEN 
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'no connection exists';
        END IF;
END $$;
```

When `dblink_get_connections()` returns no data, `connectionIsGood` is `null`;
And yet `IF (connectionIsGood != true)` never evaluates to `true`, and the exception is never raised.
If I add code such as

```
    IF connectionIsGood != true 
    THEN 
        connectionIsGood := false; 
    END IF;
```

Still, we do not enter the raise-exception block.
`INFO:  connectionIsGood=<NULL>`
If (for the purposes of testing), I simply hard-code `connectionIsGood := false;`, then I get my exception!

Something elemental is wrong; or perhaps there is a better method for establishing the absence of a connection? I also tried (unsuccessfully) to code this without the need for a *connection* variable at all: Something of the form `IF ('my_connection' not in <connection list>) THEN...`

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to the above conundrum. The key is the use of the COALESCE() function which takes an arbitrary number of arguments and returns the first non-null argument.

Thus, recoding my connection test:

```
    DO $$
    DECLARE
        connectionIsGood boolean := (select 'my_connection' = ANY (dblink_get_connections()));
    BEGIN   
        select COALESCE(connectionIsGood, FALSE) into connectionIsGood;
        RAISE INFO 'connectionIsGood=%', connectionIsGood;
        
        IF (connectionIsGood != true)
        THEN 
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'EXCEPTION: no connection exists';
        END IF;
    END $$;
```

**`connectionIsGood boolean := (select 'my_connection' = ANY (dblink_get_connections()));`**
IF (`'my_connection'` is good)
THEN `'my_connection'` is returned in the list from `dblink_get_connections()`
AND `ANY()` will return TRUE into `connectionIsGood`
ELSE `ANY()` returns NULL  into `connectionIsGood`

**`COALESCE(connectionIsGood, FALSE)`**
Will return TRUE if `connectionIsGood` is TRUE
ELSE NULL.
SO: We proceed to the next argument which is FALSE which is NOT NULL and thus is the return value from the expression. And we have what we want.

BUT the question still remains as to why a boolean NULL in `connectionIsGood` does not cause conditional `IF (connectionIsGood != true)` to evaluate to TRUE.